# mingw conflict with dropbox

Tags: dropbox, mingw-w64

I ran into a problem with `MinGW64 (gcc 4.6.3, from RTools build on CRAN)` that seems to occur when working in a Dropbox folder.  I have a large project that I build with a make file.  It compiles all the source files fine, but when I start to add all the `*.o` files to a library, I get the odd message:

> C:\Rtools\gcc-4.6.3\binar.exe: unable to rename 'project.lib'; reason:
>   File exists.

The commands being executed are:

```
ar rcs project.lib  func1.o
ar rcs project.lib  func2.o
ar rcs project.lib  func3.o
...
ar rcs project.lib  func120.o
```

There are over 100 `*.o` files.  The initial ones work, but after a random number of these the above error message occurs.  Sometimes it is on the the second ar command, sometimes on the 100th.

This make file has worked for years under Win32, Win64, linux 32, linux 64, and OSX.  And it works on this Win64 machine when I copy the folder to a non-Dropbox location.  I am guessing that there is some conflict when ar is trying to repeatedly update the library file, and Dropbox is trying to repeatedly copy the file to the cloud.

Has anyone else seen this?  Or know how Dropbox works and can explain what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this a Windows-specific issue, but probably is. Windows locks open files by default and these locks prevent files from being properly deleted/replaced. Dropbox likes to open files in its folder (in order to check/upload them).

Other than this, I've seen various issues with Dropbox when operating on files too quick (as a build process might do), including duplicated and lost files.

Comment: Thanks - this is what I suspected.  I'm just surprised that no one else seems to have mentioned it.